# Can you override an error code U071 on a Cannon MP620 printer

Tags: printer

I have no color ink and just loaded black ink in all the slots. Got an error code U071. Is there anyway to override and just print in black?

Comment: What did Cannon say when you asked them?

Answer (score 0):

The ink cartridges have a little chip on them that tells the printer which ink has been loaded into each slot. In your instance the printer is warning you that the ink is incorrectly loaded. There isn't an easy override for this without cannibalising the original colour cartridges.

Comment: Iirc you can just keep printing with empty colour carts too.